# ffmpeg streaming rtsp with parameters in the uri (url)

Tags: url, ffmpeg, video-streaming, uri

I attempt to stream a rtsp source and publish it through rtmp. But in my source url, there are several parameters:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://ip/user=admin&password=admin&channel=1&stream=0.sdp -f flv rtmp://local/live/cam1
```

how to set ffmpeg accepting such url with parameters, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

My bad, you just need put the uri under quote "", then you're ready to go.

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://ip/user=admin&password=admin&channel=1&stream=0.sdp"
```